# Database connection exception using Spring, Hibernate, JPA e C3P0

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I'm trying to configure my app to use C3P0 datasource (I can't use the datasource provided by the container).

But, when my app is starting, an exception has occurred:

**The user must supply a JDBC connection**

Bellow is my config files:

spring-config.xml:

```
<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:db" />
    <property name="user" value="dbuser" />
    <property name="password" value="passwd" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="AppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />            
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />

        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>    
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />

    </properties>

</persistence-unit> 

</persistence>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
at org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2157)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2117)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
at $Proxy286.getResultList(Unknown Source)
at com.embraer.core.jpa.DaoSupport.execQueryIndexedParameters(DaoSupport.java:327)
at com.embraer.core.jpa.DaoSupport.findByNamedQuery(DaoSupport.java:280)
at com.embraer.core.jpa.DaoSupport.findAll(DaoSupport.java:132)
at br.com.embraer.aheadpro.dao.imp.ConfigDAOImpl.findAll(ConfigDAOImpl.java:41)
at br.com.embraer.aheadpro.dao.ConfigRepoDAO.getAll(ConfigRepoDAO.java:35)
at br.com.embraer.aheadpro.service.ConfigService.refresh(ConfigService.java:27)
at br.com.embraer.aheadpro.service.ConfigService.getConfig(ConfigService.java:35)
at br.com.embraer.aheadpro.service.EmailService.init(EmailService.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:340)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
... 91 more
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help: http://thejavablog.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-the-user-must-supply-a-jdbc-connection/ , it basically says that there's something missing from persistence.xml (`<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` or maybe `hibernate.connection.provider_class`-property ?), and Hibernate's ConnectionProviderFactory chooses to create a UserSuppliedConnectionProvider, which has getConnection defined as such:

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The user must supply a JDBC connection");
}
```

I also compared this with one of our own Hibernate/JPA -setups that works just fine with C3PO, and the only differences I spotted were that we pass some more properties to c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource and some properties to org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter when defining EntityManagerFactory in the Spring configuration xml:

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">          
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jdbc.dialectClass}" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

But I doubt that could be it. There are no properties defined in our persistence.xml (at all).

Comment: Hi esaj! This is a dummy host, I can't publish the right host in internet, ok? In my file the host address is correct! Thanks!

Comment: @MarceloJuventino: Please see if my edited answer is of any help